# How to push local (behind NAT) http service into kubernetes

Tags: http, kubernetes, service, portforwarding

How to push local (behind NAT) http service into Kubernetes, so that `Pod`s inside `Kubernetes` can access this local service?

The connection must be established from the local side, since it's in local network.

One way to do so is using ssh port forwarding, but this is inconvenient because you need to set up ssh and apt stuff inside Kubernetes, and ssh connections tends to break after a long time. Lightweight solutions are preferred.

Comment: i do not think Kubernetes has anything to do with this scenario, all you need to make sure that the `http` service IP is reachable inside Kubernetes if you are trying to "reach HTTP service from Kubernetes pods"

Comment: if you are trying to reach with domain, then you might need to add host alias which can help with DNS resolution https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/#adding-additional-entries-with-hostaliases

Comment: @Adiii DNS resolution won't work since the local service won't have a public ip. I'm trying to find a "cloud native" solution rather than traditional ssh tools. The fundamentals should still be the same, a receiver server and a push client

Comment: is the Kubernetes cluster and HTTP service running in the same network?

Comment: @Adiii No, Kubernetes is running in the internet, while the local service is on my machine, running through several layers of NAT

Comment: may be this can help https://ngrok.com/, run your local service with ngrok and access the service in Kubernetes with ngrok endpoint